# css shorthand for padding/margin: 2em 2em 2em 8em;

Tags: css

Is there a shorthand for

```
padding: 2em 2em 2em 8em;
```

results in:

```
padding-top: 2em;
padding-right: 2em;
padding-bottom: 2em;
padding-left: 8em;
```

And

```
padding: 2em 2em 8em;
```

results in

```
padding-top: 2em;
padding-right: 2em;
padding-bottom: 8em;
padding-left: 2em;
```

How can i write a shorthand for

```
padding: 2em 2em 2em 8em;
```

?

Comment: You can’t, this is as short as it gets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. There simply isn't a way to shorten that any further.

The MDN [explains it well](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties) with this:

[image]